# Is there a way to generate a list of all google sheets using a specific script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to locate google sheets that are utilizing a failing script. The failure does not effect the day to day functions, so I am using this as an opportunity to do some house cleaning. I'd like to locate the sheets using the script to verify if they are still relevant, and if not, delete the sheets, rather than trouble shooting the code.

"Your script, Copy of Copy of GetFiles, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here."

Summary:

Error Message   Count
Authorization is required to perform that action.
25

Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End

4/22/19 11:12 PM    showFolderInSiteMedia   Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  4/22/19 11:12 PM

4/23/19 12:12 AM    showFolderInSiteMedia   Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  4/23/19 12:12 AM

Answer (score 1):

Simply changing the script's main function to `return console.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl())` and then checking the logs in Stackdriver should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can't check the emails as they come in?